# Generate POST requests with PHP generated buttons which calls a javascript function with parameters

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

First of all, sorry for the weird title!
Currently im facing the following problem:

I have a PHP script which creates a HTML button

```
echo '<input type="button" id="$entryID" name="change_title" value="change title" onclick="sendRequest(sendRequest($type, $entryID));" />';
```

This button should call a script, which creates a post request with the parameter

> $type     //is used to recognize which mysqli table should be adressed
>   $entryID  //is used to recognize which entry in table sould be adressed

I know that I can not create a post request with javascript because its for front-end developement.
So I have done some researches and found AJAX. So im never realy used it. But I tried to create a post request like this (in the same file):

```
<script>
    // t = type & i = ID
    function sendRequest(t, i){

        var request = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "admin_page.php",
        data: {"type": t, "id": i},
        success: function(){
            console.log('request via AJAX');
        }
    });

        return request;
    }
</script>
```

After the script has run I use the following php script to check if it has worked:

```
if(isset($_POST['type'])){
    if(isset($_POST['id'])){
        printf('Post request sent');
    }
}
```

I have checked the AJAX and the javascript documentations and have not found anything. It this process even possible?
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That AJAX you are referring to relies on jQuery, you will need to include that in your page before calling your JavaScript function. Open the developer tools in your browser (usually F12) and keep an eye on the console and network tabs as you test your code to see what is happening.

Comment: What does console show? Any errors?

Comment: aaaaah the console shows:
    Uncaught ReferenceError: $type is not defined

Comment: Is jquery included in your script?

Comment: @chris85 No, Its only PHP, HTML and AJAX

Comment: AJAX is a shorthand way of saying `asynchronous javascript and xml`. This `$.ajax` is javascript and is attempting to use a jQuery function which isn't defined because you aren't including it. Include jQuery and I think this will work; or use the native JS functions.

Answer (score 1):

I edited this answer after realizing that this was part of an echo statement. This should work:

`echo '<input type="button" id="'.$entryID.'" name="change_title" value="change title" onclick="sendRequest('.$type.','.$entryID.'));" />';`

Also I would advise against calling the JS function with variables generated via PHP. It is not elegant. Put your variables as data-* attributes and use JS to pull these attributes

Comment: That will make the PHP literal, https://3v4l.org/YmtCu. `<?=$entryID?>` won't be the value, it is in single quotes.

Comment: I think this one brought us one step closer to the solution. But the console outputs: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined